SQL запрос на сложение 2х таблиц
Есть таблица 1



reviews
ID
content
isPositiveContent
user
contentID





















таблица 2



REVIEWS_REACTIONS
reviewsID
user
isPositiveReaction

















Нужен sql запрос который вернет таблицу 1 и доп поле с разницей положительных и отрицательных значений таблицы 2 в столбце isPoitiveReaction

К таблице 1 джойните таблицу 2. В селекте перечисляете нужные поля и sum(ispositivreaction) и группируете по всем перечисленным полям, кроме тех, что в группирующих функциях

Вот пример SQL-запроса, который может решить вашу задачу:
SELECT 
    r.ID,
    r.content,
    r.isPoitiveContent,
    r.user,
    r.contentID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN rr.isPoitiveReaction = 1 THEN 1 
             WHEN rr.isPoitiveReaction = 0 THEN -1 
        END) AS reaction_diff
FROM 
    reviews r
LEFT JOIN 
    REVIEWS_REACTIONS rr ON r.ID = rr.reviewsID
GROUP BY 
    r.ID, r.content, r.isPoitiveContent, r.user, r.contentID;

